# UITableViewCell Custom accessory - get the row of accessory

Tags: iphone, uitableview, ios4, row, accessory

I have a pretty big issue. I am trying to create a favorite-button on every `UITableViewCell` in a `UITableView`. That works very good, and I currently have an action and selector performed when pressed.

```
accessory = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[accessory setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"star.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
accessory.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 15, 15);
accessory.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
[accessory addTarget:self action:@selector(didTapStar) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
cell.accessoryView = accessory;
```

And selector:

```
- (void) didTapStar {
    UITableViewCell *newCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:/* indexPath? */];

    accessory = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [accessory setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"stared.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    accessory.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 26, 26);
    accessory.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    [accessory addTarget:self action:@selector(didTapStar) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
    newCell.accessoryView = accessory;
}
```

Now, here's the problem: I want to know what row the accessory that was pressed belongs to.
How can I do this?

Thank you :)

Comment: Check this out : Simple, Quick & Easy. https://stackoverflow.com/a/55156685/5846076

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I would use the following code:

```
- (void)didTapStar:(id)sender {
  NSIndexPath *indexPath = [tableView indexPathForCell:(UITableViewCell *)[sender superview]];
}
```

Answer (score 16):

Change your action around a bit.

`- (void)action:(id)sender forEvent:(UIEvent *)event`

Inside that method:

`NSIndexPath *indexPath = [tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:[[[event touchesForView:sender] anyObject] locationInView:tableView]];`

That should get you the row's index path.

Comment: What is the role of `anyObject` here ? what does it do ?

Comment: @Giao I'm just curious, what does `anyObject` do?

Comment: @lllep @Emil 
`anyObject` is an instance method in `NSSet`, this method simple return any single object in the set. In this example, `[[[event touchesForView:sender] anyObject]` returns a `UITouch` object.

Answer (score 1):

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath {   
    // To set custom cell accessory                     
    UIImage *image = [UIImage   imageNamed:@"white_arrow_right.png"];
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake(cell.frame.size.width  - image.size.width, cell.frame.size.height - image.size.height, image.size.width, image.size.height);
    button.frame = frame;
    [button setBackgroundImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(accessoryButtonTapped:event:)  forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    button.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    cell.accessoryView = button;
}     

- (void)accessoryButtonTapped:(id)sender event:(id)event {
    NSSet *touches = [event allTouches];
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint currentTouchPosition = [touch locationInView:self.tableView];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint: currentTouchPosition];
    if (indexPath != nil){
        [self tableView: self.tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath: indexPath];
    }
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{                
    DetailViewController *detailView =[[DetailViewController alloc]init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailView animated:YES];
}
```