# Get cell title from table view

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I have a custom table view and each cell has a title and a button. When the user clicks on the button, I need the title of that cell to appear on another view. How do I get this?

Comment: Appear where? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Check out this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2562048/uitableviewcell-custom-accessory-get-the-row-of-accessory to find an answer to your question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not very tough here are the 2 solutions:

When you are creating the cell, assign tag to the label you want to get the title value (or text value)

second option is:

If you want to get the title at the didselect select method just get the cell from the table view with the help of indexpPath.row and then extract the label and it's text. You can assign the tag in the custom cell design and then extract it from cell (once you get the cell).